# Relacionar un DataSet a un tabla en un Report Service 2005

Tags: visual-studio, reportviewer

Estoy creando un reporte y ya generar mi DataSet con los datos que necesito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el diseño ya cree la tabla, el detalle es que no se como relacionarlo con el DateSet6 que ya tengo, no me lo muestra en el listado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]